# Как внутри htaccess исключить папку с редиректа на https

Tags: регулярные-выражения, .htaccess

У меня в файле .htaccess есть редирект всех запросов на протокол https

```
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !on
RewriteRule (.*) https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI}
```

Но нужно исключить с данного правила одну папку например `/my_dir`

Как это сделать?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Уже нашел ответ:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^.*/my_dir/.*$
RewriteRule (.*) https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI}
```

Comment: А так работает - `RewriteRule !/my_dir/ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI}` (только с одним `RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !on`)?

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew к сожалению не работает. Я сначала пробовал что то подобное, только `RewriteRule /([^my_dir])/ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI}` но такое правило полностью отключило редирект на https